# What is the name (general) of the dot operator in java or -> ($object->method()) in php

Tags: theory, nomenclature

I would like to know proper nomenclature.
What is the name (general) of the dot operator in java or -> ($object->method()) in php.
I mean general name such as 'reference operator' or 'dereference operator'.

Answer (score -1):

So the proper names are:

. - dot operator  http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/usingobject.html
-> - object operator  http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.php